# Is it true that multi-threading cannot take advantage of multiprocessing? If so, why?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system, multiprocessing

I'm a bit confused. Multithreading involves parallel processing so why can't we use multiple cores to run different threads? 
I found this statement in this link-
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/operating_system/os_multi_threading.htm
Please explain the statement "Multithreaded application cannot take advantage of multiprocessing."

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiprocessing in that sentence is about multiple processes, not processors.

Threads belonging to the same process aren't isolated. For example, when a thread crashes the whole program will crash.

**UPD**: sorry, I've re-read the article and realised that my initial answer was incorrect. The author seems to consider software "emulated" threads executed from the same execution unit without any parallelisation. You hardly find such threading library implementation in practice. Most of threading libraries are backed by kernel threads.

Comment: So can I say that multiple threads from a same process can be executed on multiple cores?

Comment: Usually, yes, you can

Comment: There are some Eunuchs variants where threads can only be executed on a single core. However, they are increasingly exceptional cases.